# Curl doesn't work when run with crontab

Tags: bash, cron, curl

This is my curl script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

PING_STATUS="$(netcat -vz mc.bella.wtf 25565 2>&1)"
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"embeds": [{"title": "Server Status:","color": 16027903,"description": "'"$PING_STATUS"'"}]}' "$WEBHOOK"
```

This is what I get when I run my crontab:

```
mc@ubuntu:~$ crontab -l
* * * * * /home/mc/server/ping >/tmp/mycommand.log 2>&1
mc@ubuntu:~$ cat /tmp/mycommand.log 
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

Why is my url malformed when it works fine when running the script by itself?

Comment: Is WEBHOOK defined for the cron user ?

Comment: How would I do that? It's a variable I added to my bashrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your env variable `WEBHOOK` is not recognized.

**Solution 1**

In your `/etc/environment` add:

```
WEBHOOK="http://example.org"
```

and in your crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * source /etc/environment; /home/mc/server/ping >/tmp/mycommand.log 2>&1
```

**Solution 2**

Specify `WEBHOOK` in your curl script:

```
#!/bin/bash
WEBHOOK="http://example.org"
PING_STATUS="$(netcat -vz mc.bella.wtf 25565 2>&1)"
...
```

**Solution 3**

curl script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source $HOME/.profile
PING_STATUS="$(netcat -vz mc.bella.wtf 25565 2>&1)"
...
```

$HOME/.profile

```
WEBHOOK="http://example.org"
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without doing it system wide? Webhook is a sensitive variable

Comment: Check 'Solution 3', 'Solution 2' also isn't  system wide.